# Printing lower case letters with corresponding ASCII code using a for loop

Tags: java, loops, ascii

So far this is what I have

```
System.out.println("problem 8");
int charletter = 0;
int charletter1 = 'a';
{
for (charletter = 'a'; charletter < 123; charletter++)
System.out.println(charletter);
System.out.println(charletter1);
}
}
```

The result is this list of according numbers without the letters as so:

```
Please enter the problem you want to solve:
8
problem 8
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
97
```

How do I make it so I can get a-z to show up next to or under their according number as well as getting rid of the 97 at the very end? Thanks everyone.

Comment: The `97` at the very end is the line `System.out.println(charletter1);` which will always `System.out.println(a);`. You have no braces on the `for` loop so only the first `System.out.println` is _inside_ the loop.

Comment: If you want to print characters rather than numbers ... assign the value to characters rather than numbers! Use `char` rather than `int`. Or cast to `char` before printing.

Comment: Lack of indentation makes it unclear what you intended code to do, regardless of whether incorrect bracing actually makes it do so. **Always** indent code to show program structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cast to `char` like so:

```
for (charletter = 'a'; charletter < 123; charletter++)
       System.out.println(charletter + "" + (char)charletter);
```

then get rid of `System.out.println(charletter1);` to avoid the `97` at the end.

Comment: @Ranel if you follow this solution you may also remove the `int charletter = 0;` and `int charletter1 = 'a';` that you declared outside your for loop. Provided that your for loop will be written as: `for(char charletter = 'a'; charletter < 123; charletter++)`. :)

Comment: @Whooper thanks for the edit, but I cannot approve it as it would require me to also provide further information which does indeed improve OPs code but doesn't necessarily solve the current issue. appreciated. ;-)

Comment: no worries. I did point it out in my previous comment anyway if ever OP wanted to improve his code. Cheers!

Comment: @Whooper note that if OP is to change it to `for(char charletter = 'a'; charletter < 123; charletter++)` then they would need to cast to `int` in order to get the ASCII code. either way let's just stay with the current solution as it directly solves the issue at hand.

Comment: Yup! Well I guess we provided him enough information to address his problem and further improve his code. I believe he can piece things together. Good luck OP and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the 97, remove the second `System.out.println`. The `for` loop only operates on the first `System.out.println`. To get the answer you want, use this statement instead of the first `System.out.println`:

```
for(char charletter = 'a'; charletter <= 'z'; charletter++) {
    System.out.printf("%c %d%n", charletter, (int) charletter);
}
```

Comment: `IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Character`

Comment: This approach starts with the letters, which is closer to the way the requirements are stated.